# android layoutparam support multi screen

Tags: android, multiscreen, android-layoutparams

I have a view, I want to place it at (x, y) position via WindowManager.LayoutParams.

My code is:

```
mHeadLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        mHeadLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.END;
        mHeadLayoutParams.x = -20;
        mHeadLayoutParams.y = _screenSize.y * 15 / 100;
```

But **mHeadLayoutParams.x = -20** does not same on others device screen. How can I calculate this value to my view placed on same position on multi device screen?

[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgceB.png)

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Screen ratio and density in mHeadLayoutParams.x & mHeadLayoutParams.y .
It will automatically support multi screen.

Answer (score 1):

It seem right when use : mHeadLayoutParams.x = (int)-(20 * density + 0.5f)